Dystopian book series about teenage girl who didn't die on her "death date"
I read a series of books around 2020 (the latest one was released whilst I was reading).
It was about a teen girl who lived in a world where you found out the day you died, your 'death date'. There was something about her not dying on her death date and then the government wanting to hunt her down. I recall her being in some office lab buildings at some point and then Golden Gate Bridge (maybe) in some flat or bunker...
I cannot find it for the life of me, however hard I google, and I can't find it on my Kindle app. I remember reading it electronically and feel like it may have been a freebie or included in Kindle membership or something...
Have I completely made it up?! I'm starting to wonder if I did...

Changed your title to be more descriptive. Titles like "help me find a dystopian novel" are not descriptive enough and don't work as question titles.

@Jess - Welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books?

Hmmm I would say 2020.

Possible Death Date but this was published last year but you may have read an ARC version.

Or possibly the 2 novel When series by Victoria Laurie. The first book When was previously title Death Date

I've got it! Transient (2018) by K.M. Hill. Thanks all.

If you could find out when you'll die - WOULD you?
Learning her expiry date doesn't sound like much of a birthday present to Rae, but it's been that way for everyone since the Cryptograph was introduced. A biological algorithm developed by Silicon Valley, it can determine with precise accuracy the lifespan of every human being on the planet.
Everyone gets tested when they come of age, but Rae wants to opt out. She hates how the system labels and categorizes society according to longevity - like Transients, whose short lifespan automatically renders them useless, Interims, the hard-working majority - or elite Constants, whose long lives guarantee opportunity and power.
But when Rae's intentions to avoid the test are impeded and her lifespan is revealed, the future seems set in stone.
Or does it...?


Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.
